# jQuery .toggleClass not toggling CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css

The `.highlight` class isn't working when toggled on `#button`. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
    background-color: #AABF1A;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #555BBB;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a submit button. Are you doing anything to stop your form from submitting and the page re-loading?

Comment: You will not see the toggle effect if the form is being submitted upon button click. Clicking the button results in leaving/refreshing the page.. the highlight function will not show up. If you do not wish to submit the form on button click, change button type from 'submit' to 'button'.

Comment: Does your HTML have another element with the same id `#button` ? Did you check with some inspector that the class is not there ? or are you saying that just because you are seeing the styles you expected?

Comment: Rory's answer is correct. Also, the only property that is changing in .highlight is background-color, so consider removing the others.

Comment: Ahh thanks @j08691 , good call! That was my problem. type="button" is what I need to use.

Comment: @user3421392 Here's an example of using a submit button but preventing the default action so the form isn't submitted, combined with Rory's answer about css specificity: http://jsfiddle.net/xA4Q3/

Comment: @user3421392 not really, you can also use `<button>` it's a slightly different thing compared to `<input type=button>`, if you just want some kind of button without any submitting to the server, just remove the `<form>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your jQuery code is working. The issue is that your `.highlight` class does not have a high enough specificity to override the styles placed on the element by the `#button` selector. Try changing your CSS to this:

```
#button.highlight {
    background-color: #555BBB;
}
```

Comment: To the downvoters, Ok, yes the button needs to be prevented from submitting the form, but this is why the changing of classes appears to 'not work'.

Comment: Assuming the OP has a handler preventing the submit of the form (which he could, he hasn't shown us all of his code), then this is the answer.

Comment: specifity is fine. if the form was not submitted/refreshed the highlight would have worked fine.

Comment: @NawedKhan `id` > anything.

Comment: In fact, if the specificity was fine, the question would not be *"jQuery .toggleClass not toggling CSS class"*, but *"Why is the background color of my button flashing?"*

Comment: Thanks @JasonP , I stand wrong. Though I didn't downvote any one or any comment. I just hope OP is cancelling the default submit action too.

Answer (score 1):

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9g8Jj/2/